# Best way to repeatedly vectorize matrices in R?

Tags: r, transformation

So my data is essentially organized as 58 10x3 matrices stacked on top of one another such that the resulting data is 580x3. Something like this:

```
dat <- matrix(rnorm(1740), nrow = 580, ncol = 3)
```

I would like to vectorize each of these 10x3 matrices as to produce a single row of data such that the resulting matrix would be 58x30. I've used the as.vector() function to produce one of these rows as follows:

```
row1 <- as.vector(t(dat[1:10])
row2 <- as.vector(t(dat[11:20])
```

I could repeat this function 58 times and rbind the vectors into the desired matrix, but I'm hoping that there is an easier way to produce the desired matrix. I figured looping would be involved, but I'm pretty inexperienced with this process and can't quite figure out how to format a loop to do what I want.

Comment: Note that using `dat[1:10]` will vectorize only the first column of `dat`, not all the columns as you desire. Do you need all columns to be vectorized on each slice?

Comment: @Chriss,  Not so.  dat[ix] will regard the entire matrix as a vector and take the ix elements of that vector.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yes, completely agree. My point was that @Jeremy is asking  to convert "10x3 matrices as to produce a single row", so, in this case, he wants to obtain a vector of length 30 for each of the 58 matrices. Having dat[1:10] will give him only a row of length 10 with elements coming from the first column of the first 10 rows of `dat`. What I assume he meant is  `row1 <- as.vector(t(dat[1:10, ])` `row2 <- as.vector(t(dat[11:20, ])` instead of `row1 <- as.vector(t(dat[1:10])` and `row2 <- as.vector(t(dat[11:20])`

Answer (score 0):

```
dat2 <- matrix(t(dat), ncol = 30, byrow = TRUE)

all.equal(dat2[1, ], as.vector(t(dat[1:10, ]))) # TRUE
all.equal(dat2[2, ], as.vector(t(dat[11:20, ]))) # TRUE
```